# how to use the facebook newsfeed in my web app?

Tags: facebook

Well, I have to do a web app and I must be able to read the news feed of my clients.

First of all is it possible? If it is, does anyone have knows where it is in the Facebook documentation (I didn't find it)?

Comment: This question is too broad, and you should show your previous efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need the `/me/feed`, `/me/posts` or `/me/home` endpoint after authorizing the users to your App, check out the Facebook docs for information and example code:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/feed
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/home

But as it says in the docs, the `read_stream` permission is required. That permission will only get approved by Facebook on platforms without a native Facebook client (Smart TVs, Fridges with Internet, ...) and not for Desktop browsers or Android/iOS Apps. Without approval, only users with a role in the App can use that permission (Admin, Developer, Tester). Read more about the review process (and which permissions you need to get approved) in the docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

Here is another Facebook docs link you may want to check out, about `read_stream` and other permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1

Comment: please explain why, if you downvote something. my answer is 100% correct.

Answer (score 0):

To get the news feed of your client you need to make a call to this edge...https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/User-id/home?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   Just refer the following link..........https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/home...........  hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the Graph Api for that.

You find more information about it on the facebook developers page: [Using the graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1)

The best way for you to get started is probably using the Graph Api Explorer. This tool helps you to explore the Graph API from your browser. Test permissions, query data and learn more about the Graph API syntax.

You find this tool here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/

Comment: why are you downvoting my answer? my answer is correct.